# How to un/marshall a list with JAXB in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala, jaxb

I'm trying to read some XML into case class and vice versa. Everything seems to be fine but list attribute. I have no idea about the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of scala.collection.immutable.List
```

btw, may be the JAXB doesn't fit for my purpose at all and I should use native scala ways for XML handling? But my target XSD is very large and I think it would be painful.

Here is my code:

```
package common

import java.io.StringReader
import scala.annotation.target.field
import javax.xml.bind.annotation._
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters._
import javax.xml.bind._
import common.Types.{xmlTypeAdapter, xmlElement}

@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
case class Person(
   @xmlElement(required = true) fullname: String,
   username: String,
   age: Int,
   favNumbers: List[Int]){

  private def this() = this("", "", 0, List())
}

object JaxbTest {

  val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classOf[Person])

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val personXml1 = "<person><fullname>Martin Krasser</fullname><username>mrt1nz</username><age>30</age><favNumbers><favNumber>73</favNumber><favNumber>47</favNumber></favNumbers></person>"
     assert(context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(personXml1)) ==
       Person("Martin Krasser", "mrt1nz", 30, List(73,47)))
     context.createMarshaller.marshal(Person("Martin Krasser", "mrt1nz", 30, List(73,47)), System.out)
  }
}

package object Types {
  type xmlElement = XmlElement@field
  type xmlTypeAdapter = XmlJavaTypeAdapter@field
}
```

Comment: Did it give a stack trace?  If you get stuck, consider using Java collections for JAXB and wrapping them using scala.collection.JavaConverters.

Comment: Definitely will need to use Java collections

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try java's ArrayList instead of immutable scala's List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was noticed in the comments, Java collections work just fine.

I've published the code [here](https://gist.github.com/vic0nt/7689849)